# TypeScript Err: "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

**[Hello!][1]**

I'm getting this TypeScript error
{ "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{ 0: { image: string; title: string; text: string; }; 1: { image: string; title: string; text: string; }; 2: { image: string; title: string; text: string; }; }'.",
}. TS7053

Unsure where my interfaces need to be added or if req at all?

**this is highlighted**
setCurrent(carouselData[event.target.getAttribute("data-Testimonials")])

what to change them to . I have no idea where I am going wrong, as I've only been coding for a month.

***My Code for a carousel***:

````
interface CarouselCardProperties {
   image: string;
   title: string;
   text: string;
}

export default function Testimonials() {
   const carouselData = {
       0: {
           image: tobi,
           title: "I no longer have to howl at the moon to call for my lady !!",
           text: "Tobi ~ Vancouver, Canada",

       },
       1: {
           image: girly,
           title: "With Enrico going on dates, we have more time to ourselves!",
           text: " Gina ~ Rome, Italy",

       },
       2: {
           image: loveshades,
           title: "I no longer have to worry about staying clean, I kitties licking me every night.  I have Love Shades on.",
           text: " Princess ~ Georgia, USA",
       },
   };

   const [current, setCurrent] = useState(carouselData[0])

   const [active, setActive] = useState(0)

   const handleSetClick = (event:any) => {

       setCurrent(carouselData[event.target.getAttribute("data-Testimonials")])
       setActive(event.target.getAttribute("data-Testimonials"))

   };
   return (
       <Container>
           <Img src={current.image} />
           <Title>{current.title}</Title>
           <Text>{current.text}</Text>
           <div>
               {Object.keys(carouselData).map(index => (
                   <Span
                       onClick={(event:any) => handleSetClick(event)}
                       data-Testimonials={index}
                       key={index} />
               ))}
           </div>
       </Container>
   )
}```


 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9CwZ.png
````

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a `data-Testimonials` attribute?

Just pass directly the index to `handleSetClick`:

```
const handleSetClick = (index: keyof typeof carouselData) => {
    setCurrent(carouselData[index])
    setActive(index)
};

return (
   <Container>
       <Img src={current.image} />
       <Title>{current.title}</Title>
       <Text>{current.text}</Text>
       <div>
           {Object.keys(carouselData).map(index => (
               <Span
                   onClick={() => handleSetClick(index)}
                   key={index} />
           ))}
       </div>
   </Container>
)
```

Comment: Yes that is easier isn't it ! Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: You're welcome 

Answer (score 1):

The code

```js
const carouselData = {
    0: {
        // ...
    }
}
```

defines `carouselData` data to use numerical indices, but you index it with `event.target.getAttribute("data-Testimonials")`, which implicitly has any type.
I would strongly type your `event` parameter, so `event.target.getAttribute("data-Testimonials")` has a string type. I would then redefine `carouselData` to use string indices like so:

```js
const carouselData = {
    '0': {
         // ...
     },
    '1': {
         // ...
     }
}
```

It's generally best to avoid `any` type whenever possible to avoid these kinds of situations.